# Dual Internet connections in active/standby mode without BGP

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, cisco-asa, firewall

[image]

hello everyone
attached is my diagram in which i am facing problem as you can see i have two internet links from two ISPs in which i want failover between two ISPs without using BGP or NAT because i am also going to configure Site-to-Site VPN over the two ASA which also needs to be in failover for each other can anyone please give an opinion regarding this problem

Comment: So you only want outbound failover because BGP is required for inbound failover?  Please clarify any dynamic routing protocols running between the ASAs and the 6500s.

Comment: actually this scenario could be done with BGP easily but in here i am not going with BGP  i want like this if my first ISP is down i have to be connected with my outside customers through the second ISP since i am also configuring VPN in the ASA the at the time when ISP 1 is down i don't have to reestablish a new VPN tunnel with my customers.
 
between the two 6500s i am thinking of VSS and the routing protocol that will be used will be EIGRP

Comment: Your diagram isn't workable.  The outside interfaces of the firewalls need to be connected together (on the same subnet).  Also do you have your own registered IP space?    As @generalnetworkerror says, you can only control the outbound path.

Comment: if the diagram is not workable what is your suggestions to make it workable i can take my own registered IP space but the problem will be that i can not broadcast those IP address through BGP(not Supported by the ISP).
and even if i get my own Range Of IP address the IPs will be terminated in routers and so i can't NAT those IP address because the VPNs will be created on the ASA for which i will need Public IPs in order to make VPN tunnel

Comment: If you can't use BGP, then you can't influence the inbound path.  That pretty much stops you right there.  You can't tell ISP 1 that you've lost connectivity and they should stop forwarding traffic to you.  You need some way of communicating your status to the ISPs, which is the whole purpose of a routing protocol.  I'm surprised that neither ISP will peer with you.

Comment: i talked with my ISPs they are saying that they can advertise my own IP address space statically without using the BGP but somethings else that they mentioned is that my IP address Block can only be advertised only by one of the ISPs the second ISP will not  advertise it because it is already advertised by the first ISP if the second ISP is not advertising the my IP address block then again i lose the point of having a redundant ISP connectivity "Ron" what is your suggestion regarding this problem